# Removing a Cocoapod from the Specs Repo

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cocoapods

This post is in regards to two Cocoapods of which I am the owner of:

- https://cocoapods.org/?q=id.me (There's only one cocoapod that shows up and I can't link to it because it's broken)
- https://cocoapods.org/?q=idmeweb (There's only one cocoapods that shows up and I can't link to it because it's broken).

I need the first CocoaPod (which has already been deprecated), `ID.me WebVerify` to be completely removed as it's podspec points to a personal repo of mine, http://github.com/artsabintsev/Harpy/. The actual location it should have pointed to no longer exists, and my previous employer, ID.me, has asked me have it removed.

I need the second CocoaPod, `https://cocoapods.org/pods/IDmeWebVerify`, to work. Apparently, clicking on the link does nothing. My previous employer, ID.me, has asked me to figure out how to get it fixed.

Thank you for any and all assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are `pod trunk x` [commands to deprecate and delete](https://guides.cocoapods.org/terminal/commands.html#group_trunk) if you have admin access to them.

Comment: oh wait, I've seen that command. I was looking for something that would remove the entire Pod from the Specs repo and delist it from the web (as if it had never existed). Is that possible at all?

Comment: For future visitors to this question, the conversation continued here: https://github.com/CocoaPods/trunk.cocoapods.org/issues/226